# How do I edit the 'Contact Edit' page layout

Tags: custom-field, page-layout

I want to add a middle name field to the Contact Edit page. While I can edit the Contact Detail page layout, I can not find a way to edit the page layout for the Contact Edit page.

Answer (score 1):

Name field in standard Contact object is a combination field(Concatenation of FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix). If you want to separately show middle name field in edit page, you might have to override edit page with a custom visualforce page. API names of fields on Contacts and description of fields can be found in below link,

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm

Comment: Thx Victor. However when adding or editing a contact there is no place for a middle name. When viewing a contact I understand that the name shown is a combination field but when I edit the contact or add a new one there is no place on that page to add a middle name.

Comment: It looks like salesforce will enable if you contact them. Check the link - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Middle-Name-and-Suffix-Fields&language=en_US . If this is not working, you can create a custom visualforce page to override edit page, which gives full control.

Comment: @Victor you are right. It's a case with SFDC. Worth putting in your answer above.